# Initial job has not accepted any resources; Error with spark in VMs

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have three Ubuntu VMs (clones) in my local machine which i wanted to use to make a simple cluster. One VM to be used as a master and the other two as slaves. I can ssh every VM from every other one succesfully and i have the ip's of the two slaves in the conf/slaves file of the master and the master's ip in the spark-env.sh of every VM.When I run 
`start-slave.sh spark://master-ip:7077`
from the slaves,they appear in the spark UI. But when i try to run things in parallel i always get the message about the resources. For testing code i use the scala shell
`spark-shell --master://master-ip:7077`  and `sc.parallelize(1 until 10000).count`.

Comment: Do You mean that warn: `WARN TaskSchedulerImpl: Initial job has not accepted any resources; check your cluster ui to ensure that workers are registered and have sufficient memory` , how many cores you assign to each VM ?

Comment: Yes. The VMs have 4 cores (cpu threads) each.

Answer (score 1):

Do You mean that warn: `WARN TaskSchedulerImpl: Initial job has not accepted any resources; check your cluster ui to ensure that workers are registered and have sufficient memory`

This message will pop up any time an application is requesting more resources from the cluster than the cluster can currently provide.

Spark is only looking for two things: Cores and Ram. Cores represents the number of open executor slots that your cluster provides for execution. Ram refers to the amount of free Ram required on any worker running your application.

> Note for both of these resources the maximum value is not your System's max, it is the max as set by the your Spark configuration.

If you need to run multiple Spark apps simultaneously then you’ll need to adjust the amount of cores being used by each app.

If you are working with applications on the same node you need to assign cores to each application to make them work in parallel: [ResourceScheduling](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/spark-standalone.html#resource-scheduling)

> If you use VMs (as in your situation): assign only one core to each VM
>   when you first create it or whatever relevant to your system
>   resource capacity as by now spark request `4 cores for each * 2 VMs = 8 core` which you don't have.

This is a tutorial i find that could help you: [Install Spark on Ubuntu: Standalone Cluster Mode](https://www.programcreek.com/2018/11/install-spark-on-ubuntu-standalone-mode/)

Further Reading: [common-spark-troubleshooting](https://www.datastax.com/blog/2014/10/common-spark-troubleshooting)

Comment: I have tried different settings. I even made the VMs to use 2 cores and 1GB ram.So 4 cores in total and 2GB ram. I have 6 core-12 thread CPU machine so this shouldnt be a problem. But no matter the settings i always get the same result. Also the tutorial is the one i used to make this setup...

Comment: It may be a networking issue, try Disable Firewall on the slaves ,then try again.

Comment: see your `$SPARK_HOME/conf/spark-env.sh` on each slave and search for `SPARK_EXECUTOR_MEMORY` if it is set to much higher than the VM have.
also, in `$SPARK_HOME/conf/spark-default.sh` in the master node and search for `spark.executor.memory`.

Comment: Also, try to set number of max cores in your code like this: `SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().set("spark.cores.max", "2"); `

Comment: The firewall in the VMs is by defauld disables. Also i set SPARK_EXECUTOR_MEMORY=6G in the spark-env.sh. In the spark-default.sh the spark.executor.memory wasnt there but i set it to 4G. Also when i run things in the spark UI it shows that indeed 2 cores are running per VM. Still the same results

Comment: You said that you assigned 1GB ram to each of the slave VM, How is that you set memeory to 6GB ram in the configuration.

What i think is happening is that spark request more resources than been assigned to it on each VM, so please try to make the configuration reflect the resources you assigned to each VM on creation.

Comment: yeah that was a mistake , i misunderstood ur earlier comment. Still no matter what the ram i use i always get the same. But still by default the spark uses 1GB of ram. So the ram i use can't be the problem. For a simple count i think 1GB or more should be fine...

Comment: I will try, recreate the problem myself, and get back to you.

Comment: I simulated the whole process by creating a master node with two slave nodes on AWS. All things worked fine for me and i ran my spark job, without any errors.